# how to save image into directory via url

Tags: php

how to save image into directory via url i try find solution but not get any thing just saw below script i just need in this script how i add directory name?

```
$url    = "http://www.hdwallpapersplus.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/farrari-sports-cars-13821367-1280-960.jpg";
$data   = file_get_contents($url);
$name   = explode("/", $url);
$handle = fopen($name[count($name)-1], "w");
fwrite($handle, $data);
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: So you found this code online and now you would like somebody to explain you how it works? Is that about right?

Comment: Many hosts doesn't admit cross-origin that is bandwidth theft.

Comment: yeh right right and i found this code form stackoverflow

Comment: @Lame-up-duck i really need this bcoz i am working on social network which have link sharing system but we found website very slow wehen content get image from url thats y we need to save image on own server

Comment: @PatrickGruber yeh right right and i found this code form stackoverflow

Comment: Your code consists of two function calls. **file_get_contents** gets some content from a file and returns it. **file_put_contens** saves data to a local file. The variable **$url** is the URL you need to load your data from and **$img** is the destination file. You would be using it correctly. If you get any errors, you should post them. Maybe @Lame-up-duck is right and there are some problems with you PHP configuration.

Comment: @PatrickGruber check question i edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see, you just want a hint on how change that code to save your images into a specific folder (in your case the folder called "images"), I'll assume that your folder in the same directory as your script.

So all you need to change is that line:

> $handle = fopen($name[count($name)-1], "w");

in this line you give your image its name extracted from the url it self, so you just need to replace it with the following line:

> $handle = fopen("images/".$name[count($name)-1], "w");

where I've added your folder name to the image name, which will mean

1. get the image
2. save it in the folder images in the script directory

I hope this helps, but better is to try understanding the code before using it, some comments contains good hints, and you can refer to http://php.net  website to search each function from that script to get a cleaner idea

Comment: @AbuRomaïssae why you used fopen instead of file_get/put_contents?

Comment: @Lame-up-duck, I didn't use anything, I've only answered his question, in the script he presented he was using fopen, so I kept it, no need to make it even more confusing for him

Comment: @AbuRomaïssae, sorry, in his first post he used file_put/get contents. I dind't see last edit. ;)